# Choosing resistor for the emitter pin of the TIP41C!

Tags: power-supply, transistors, resistors, schematics

There are many ways to choose current-dividing emitter resistor values for transistors in parallel on the internet. However, what I found is that only if the voltage from the collector pin are fixed with the formula `R = V / A`. (There is also website that explains `Ve = Vb - 0.7 / A`)

The problem with my circuit is that the voltage can be regulated with the TIP41C, which acts as the Linear Voltage Regulator.
Also, because I'm not familiar with this type of field, I admit that.

**This is the schematic I'm working on.**

[image: schematic]
<sub>Original: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHrIc.png</sub>

[image]
<sub>Original: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2yR2.png</sub>

- The measured voltage after the Transformer, Diode Bridge (D1), and Capacitor (C1) is 25 VDC, with a current that can be handled by the transformer up to a maximum of 10 A.
- This circuit can adjust the output voltage from 1 volt to 13 volts based on the temporary measurement results.

**Disclaimer**: I'm not an electrician and also not very good at this, so maybe you guys can help me solve this problem, and yes, please also explain the steps easily!

**Note**: If something is unclear, please ask.

Comment: `current that can be handled by the transformer up to a maximum of 10 A` what is the maximum load current that the load can draw from DC output? Since your circuit is basically a capacitive load to the transformer I'd assume the max DC current to be 5~6 Amps.

Comment: Is the bulb just an incandescent? And that's the entire load?

Comment: Please check in the datasheet what’s the specified min and max beta/hfe at the worst case load, Vge min and max and Vce min and max at worst case. Assume the worst for one of them and best case for two of them. What current division did you end up with? Close to 100/0/0 %? How close to 33/33/33 % do you need to get to stay within limits?

Comment: @RohatKılıç, Yes, right! In the real scenario, the load only consumes about a maximum of 6 Amperes (continuously). I don't use it on top of that.

Comment: @periblepsis yes, nothing else.

Comment: @winny, well, I already have the datasheet. However, I think I am not able to understand all that. can you explain to me? or is there a site or something for me to understand that? Thanks.

Comment: Start with what you understand and we’ll take it from there. Your concern is current sharing between your bipolar transistors in parallel? What causes it?

Comment: In short, I want to power a load of 12V 70W (±6A) incandescent bulbs. Well, the previous transistor (D313 ×3) was damaged by overheating. 

Then I bought a new transistor with a slightly larger current, namely TIP41C as much as 3. And the plan is to parallel it like the previous circuit but with a current dividing resistor on each emitter pin.

Well, now I'm confused about how to find the right emitter resistor value to parallel the 3 TIP41C so that the current is evenly distributed.

Comment: To be honest, this power supply is not made or designed by me, it was actually given by my neighbors because they don't use it anymore.

When the 3 D313 transistors are damaged due to overheating, the components and the circuit are still original. (looks like a home manufacturer)

Comment: @Zievfik Thanks. Knowing it is incandescent and also that your power supply has limited current capacity suggests that you may like to have both current limiting as well as voltage regulation. This isn't difficult. If you want to see part of why, then look at the [relative resistivity vs temperature chart](https://personal.tcu.edu/ystrzhemechn/Classes/2012/Summer/Labs/lab22ss.htm) found on this page. There's quite a difference as the filament heats up. With 25 V overhead, a circuit shouldn't be difficult. But if you want to power more than one then 6 A times the number must be provided.

Comment: @Zievfik How much of the power supply came from your neighbors? All of it? If so, that schematic is wonky (not-good) and should be altered, perhaps significantly. This then gets back to the transformer itself. We need to know as much detail about the transformer as possible. (Well ... I do, anyway. Others can speak for themselves.) I also need to know if you are powering **one** bulb? Or 50 bulbs. You used the English plural form of bulb (writing bulbs) which makes me wonder how many of these you plan to operate.

Comment: @periblepsis, Sorry for making you confused. This is due to the automatic correction of the translation site I'm using. Actually only one 12V 70W incandescent light bulb. **How much of the power supply came from your neighbors?** - Only one unit. The following are the transformer specifications: input voltage 0-100-220 AC with a copper diameter width of about 0.75mm, output voltage ±17-18V AC with a copper diameter width of 1.25mm, then the current based on the label on the power supply box is 10 Amperes. But I don't think it's pure 10A, maybe 5-8A.

Comment: @periblepsis, **also that your power supply has limited current capacity suggests that you may like to have both current limiting as well as voltage regulation.** - What do you mean besides voltage regulation is it also current limiting? Is something like [this site](https://electronicsarea.com/voltage-regulator-using-current-limiter/) explain ?

Comment: @Zievfik Yes, that site has a rough sketch of where I was headed. T2 and R represent the key idea. And simple. Such a linear system will not nearly so efficient as a switcher. So heat dissipation is a must. But they are easier to dash out. The reason for the current limiting (my reason only) is that Tungsten starts out with low resistance and therefore will attempt to allow a higher current at first. You can avoid most of that by using that current limiter. It will dissipate heat. But it doesn't matter because in linear system that heat gets dissipated somewhere, anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the transistors are connected in parallel they share the collector current according to their intrinsic emitter terminal resistance, \$r_e\$, which has a dynamic value:

$$
r_e=\frac{V_T}{I_C}
$$

where \$V_T\$ is the thermal voltage (~26mV for 25°C but increases with temperature) and \$I_C\$ is the collector current (in your case, this is a portion of the return current or load current).

\$r_e\$ is a device-specific value and can differ amongst the same brand and model devices. So, when multiple transistors are connected in parallel, one with the lowest \$r_e\$ will take most of the current. And the worse part is, since \$r_e\$ is temperature-dependent, a higher collector (load) current will increase the junction temperature more than the others. So \$V_T\$ will increase, therefore \$r_e\$ decreases further and the transistor takes even more current. And this cycle goes forever and may result in device failure.

An extra resistor, \$R_E\$, connected in series with the emitter effectively increases the total resistance to \$r_e'=r_e + R_E\$. So the sharing percentages will now be set by \$r_e'\$. The idea is to select a high enough \$R_E\$ compared to \$r_e\$ so we can neglect it i.e. \$r_e'\approx R_E\$.

---

Assuming the total load current is 6A and you want the TIP41Cs to share this current equally i.e. 2A per transistor. And assuming the temperature (junction temperature of the transistor) is 80°C.

At 80°C the thermal voltage will be 30 mV, so under the perfect conditions the emitter terminal resistance of each should be \$r_e=30mV/2A=15m\Omega\$. But this happens in an ideal world.

If T3-T4-T5 share the currents by 2A, 1.5A and 2.5A initially (i.e. %33, %25, %42) then their emitter terminal resistances will be \$15m\Omega\$, \$20m\Omega\$ and \$12m\Omega\$, respectively. If you put a series resistance of ten times the highest one i.e. \$R_E=0.2\Omega\$ then the total emitter resistances for the transistors will be \$215m\Omega\$, \$220m\Omega\$ and \$212m\Omega\$. Now the ratios are quite close.

$$
\mathrm{I_1 \cdot r_{e1}' \approx I_2 \cdot r_{e2}' \approx I_3 \cdot r_{e3}' \\
I_1+I_2+I_3=6A}
$$

Solving the equation set above should give almost equal collector currents i.e. 2A and maybe ± 50 to 80 mA, I didn't calculate.

But each \$0.2\Omega\$ resistor dissipates an extra 0.8W or 2.4W in total.

If that extra 2.4W is too much then you can decrease \$R_E\$ and solve the equations above until you find an acceptable point.

Please note that it doesn't end with this. The most important part is to attach the transistors to the same heatsink so they have equal (almost) junction temperatures. This will help further to equalise the collector currents.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I found in simulation (load = 1 Ohm, 0.1 Ohm in power emitters).

Not very good power supply (not stable, not current protected).

[image]

Comment: how do you get the value of the emitter resistor 0.1? can you explain?

Comment: 1 V accross this resistor of 0.1 Ohm (1V / 10 A=0.1 Ohm). Note that power is r*(i/3)^2= 0.1 *3.3*3.3= 1 W. A resistor of 0.050 Ohm should also be "good".